# Build maven submodules and run ant task

Tags: maven

I have maven project with modules. I want on run `mvn install` that install phase of all modules is executed and after that ant task from parent project is executed. I have the following parent pom.xml

```
<project>
  ...
     <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                                <execution>
                                   <phase>install</phase>    
                                       ant task
                                 </execution>
                             </executions>
             </plugin>
          </plugins>
 <modules>
     <module>module1</module>
     <module>module2</module>
 </modules>
```

But when i run `mvn install` ant task is executed in all modules, not in the root project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent pom is used to hold general information about the underlying modules. So this behaves as expected.

Move your ant task to a separate module and inside this module you can call your ant script after the install phase.